# Change Directory Browsing Page in IIS 7.5

Tags: web-server, asp.net, iis-7.5

**NOTE:** This post is tagged ASP.NET but really that's just one of the language (families) in which I could write it.  I really need assistance with configuring IIS (7.5).

I have found many scripts and ideas to effect this but I require that it's not a "drop-in" replacement, as in it must work globally for any possibly directory from one codebase.  The one I'm working with: ***http://mvolo.com/get-nice-looking-directory-listings-for-your-iis-website-with-directorylistingmodule***.

Here is what my server pumps out when I try to go anywhere (after putting **web.config**
in the main directory):

[image: Configuration]

I've tried registering all the DLLs, etc. to no avail.  I didn't build anything and it's all stored in `C:\server\www\etc\aspdirlist\`.  Here is a snapshot of my application pool: http://img444.imageshack.us/img444/8196/screenoa.png

Here is the `web.config` file just for reference:

```xml
<configuration>
  <!-- ShellIconHandler configuration section declaration -->
  <configSections>
    <section name="iconHandler" type="Mvolo.ShellIcons.Web.ShellIconHandlerConfigurationSection" />
    <section name="directoryListing" type="Mvolo.DirectoryListing.DirectoryListingModuleConfigurationSection" />
  </configSections>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="DirectoryListingModule" />
      <add name="DirectoryListingModule" type="Mvolo.DirectoryListing.DirectoryListingModule" />
    </modules>

    <handlers>
      <remove name="StaticFile" />
      <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" />
      <add name="iconhandler" path="geticon.axd" verb="GET" type="Mvolo.ShellIcons.Web.ShellIconHandler" />
    </handlers>

    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>

  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="geticon.axd" verb="GET" type="Mvolo.ShellIcons.Web.ShellIconHandler" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="DirectoryListingModule" type="Mvolo.DirectoryListing.DirectoryListingModule" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>

<!--

Configuration:
enabled: whether or not the directory listing is enabled.  
  If its not, 403 Access Denied is returned
templatePage: the template page that should be used to 
  display the directory listing

-->

  <directoryListing enabled="true" templatePage="~/dirlisting.aspx" />

  <!-- 

  Icon Handler
  Retrieves the shell icon for the specified file name.

  Configuration:
    enabled: whether or not the icon handler is enabled (true by default)
    enableClientCaching: whether client caching of the icons should be allowed (true by default)
    enableServerCaching: whether the server should cache the icon bitmaps (true by default)
    alwaysUseExtension: whether the handler should always look up the icon by extension 
      and not try to use the full file name (false by default)

  -->

  <iconHandler enabled="true" 
               alwaysUseExtension="true" 
               enableClientCaching="true" 
               enableServerCaching="true" />

</configuration>
```

I do not have any security of which I know configured.  Thanks.

Comment: It might be a good idea to edit this post to ask for help with the first link you provided.  If that's what you want... why doesn't it work?

Comment: Can you walk through the exact steps you took to install this module (did you build it from source?), where you put it on the file-system and also tell us how you've configured your site security and application pool? Without this we're going to be pulling at straws.

Comment: @Kev See my update

Answer (score 1):

It is a .NET assembly, not a COM DLL so you don't need to register it.

What you've got is a pretty generic "I can't load the DLL" error. It could fail to load for a number of reasons. Most likely place to start is the web process can't access where you've stored the DLL. I'd double check that first. I'd also take a gander at the event log, that might have a key detail or two.

If that doesn't help, you can turn on FREB which will probably help you pinpoint the issue.

Comment: I appreciate your input and will look into the issue per your advice.